# wait for multiple concurrent http put block requests to complete and then fire the last one, put block list http call in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I just want to wait for all concurrent HTTP calls completed then make another HTTP request.

here is my code ...

```
const observable = requestData.map(x => this.blobService.addNewVideo(x.uniqueName, x.chunk, x.base64BlockId));
from(observable).pipe(mergeAll(5)).subscribe(
(event: HttpEvent<any>)=>{
  switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
      this.progress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total!) * 100);
      console.log(`uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
      break;
    case HttpEventType.Response:
      console.log('Successfully uploaded',event.body,' : ',event.status,event.statusText);
      }
    }
  );
```

here are successfully uploaded all the chunks but the problem is that I am unable to wait for all requests completed to make another HTTP request. how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wait for all the request to complete, you should use `forkJoin`  and the you can use `concatMap` for the next request.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: yes, but there is a problem with forkjion, it calls all the requests parallelly but in my case, there is n number of HTTP requests, it depends on chunks. I want to 4 concurrent requests, then another 4, after completed then want to call commit all the chunks that I uploaded.

Comment: you can split it into chunks of 4 (do `forkJoin) and then call a recursive function. Combine them with `concatMap` till all requests are done

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forkJoin` in order to wait for an array of observables to complete and return the observables containing all results. After that you can use `switchMap` in order to "switch" to the final call you want to make. The subscription will then contain the result of the last call.

**Note:**

- In order to perform side effects (like setting the loading progress) you should use `tap` operator
- You should rework your approach about setting the `progress`, since you currently have only a single value. Unfortunately you have an array of requests, where you probably want to set the progress for each call individually. Now all observables would simply write to the same `progress` variable resulting in `progress` containing only the actual progress of the last emitted event.

```
const requests = requestData.map((x) =>
      this.blobService.addNewVideo(x.uniqueName, x.chunk, x.base64BlockId).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          switch (event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
              this.progress = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total!) * 100);
              console.log(`uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
              break;
            case HttpEventType.Response:
              console.log(
                'Successfully uploaded',
                event.body,
                ' : ',
                event.status,
                event.statusText
              );
          }
        })
      )
    );
    forkJoin(requests)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (results) => null //here you can return the finall call.
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res) //result of last call
      );
  }
```